# Disable user browsing in Azure Active Directory for standard users

Tags: powershell, azure, azure-active-directory

I created a new AAD user without any special permissions (no admin, just a user). Now, when I login using the `Connect-MSOLService` cmdlet and retrieve all users using `Get-MSOLUser` I can see every user within that directory.

Why and am I able to change that?

Background: I want to use a single AAD instance for multiple SAAS applications and want to prevent that a user can browse all users.

Comment: well, this is pretty much what you get in AD... you could restrict that in AD, but I haven't heard about a way to do that in AAD.

Comment: @4c74356b41 Thanks so far, hopefully I get some more information about that.

Comment: You can do that because you're an authenticated user and default permission allow you to. If you connect to an AD you want to read that so it makes sense. A default AD installation is meant for a single tenant. Otherwise you will have to change the permissions and think about your design. See [this](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/resources/samples/active-directory-dotnet-webapp-multitenant-openidconnect/?cdn=disable)  and [this](http://serverfault.com/questions/634134/creating-a-multi-tenant-ad-environment).

Comment: @seth or 4c74356b41 please consider to add your comment as an answer so I can accept it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Actually, there is a way to disable user browsing in an AAD using the `Set-MsolCompanySettings` from the MSOnline module:

```
Set-MsolCompanySettings -UsersPermissionToReadOtherUsersEnabled $false
```

Comment: Is there a way to have this set to `$false` but make an RBAC role to allow some users to continue to read other user (besided being an admin)?

Answer (score 2):

In Azure AD, Users and groups are created in a flat structure without OU and GPO. You can't restrict the user's permission to a specific scope. The user can view all the user information in Azure AD.

To isolate the users from different scopes, you can create multiple directories for Azure AD, and configure the SaaS applications as multi-tenant application for AAD.

You can refer to the article below for more details about Azure AD Directory role.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/active-directory-assign-admin-roles

Comment: I found a way thus accepted my own answer. Anyway, thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

If you connect to an Active Directory you usually want to read some data. As such if you're authorized to do that you can easily access information that is available and particularly "sensitive" (e.g. you can't read private keys of user objects easily). If you look at the history of Active Directory and it's typical usage within companies, it's likely that only single tenant (company) using it at a given time. As such there were even less reason to restrict the access.

If you want to have multiple tenants use the same AD you will have to figure out a scheme that works for you and setup the proper permissions yourself.

Helpful articles for this could be:

- [Build a multi-tenant SaaS web application using Azure AD & OpenID Connect](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/resources/samples/active-directory-dotnet-webapp-multitenant-openidconnect/?cdn=disable)
- Question: [Creating a multi-tenant AD environment](https://serverfault.com/questions/634134/creating-a-multi-tenant-ad-environment)